# Dual boot, ubuntu won't boot!

Tags: 11.10, wubi

I tried to install Ubuntu using Wubi at my PC with Windows 7 64bit OS.
I've noticed that Wubi is downloading ubuntu-11.10-desktop-**amd64**.iso.torrent
but, my PC is intel CORE i5, but, I thought that this won't be an issue.

After Wubi finished the installation, I restarted the PC, and chosed Ubuntu as an OS to start, but, then, nothing happened, I waited too long, all I saw is a blinking cursor at a black screen.

Any idea ? shall I try to use ubuntu-11.10-desktop-**i386**.iso.torrent instead ? is there any risk to harm windows 7 booting ?

Comment: try with i386. It won't affect the windows boot. Wubi installation is just another windows software. you can install an unintstall  at any time.

Comment: have you tried **recovery mode**?

Comment: no, I didn't try recovery mode, but, how to do so ?

Comment: i am downloading i386, I hope it will be installed correctly

Comment: amd64 works fine on intel 64 bit, so this is not the problem. Post more of your specs, and also the wubi log file.

Answer (score 1):

- Uninstall everything (previous Ubuntu wubi).
- Disconnect your internet modem.
- Now install Ubuntu using wubi (32-bit or 64-bit; it does not matter).
- After installing wubi reboot your machine.
- Select Ubuntu at start-up.
- Let Ubuntu install in your PC (You don't need to do anything).

Comment: but, won't wubi ask for internet connection ?

Comment: If wubi.exe will get internet connection then it will going to download latest ubuntu iso file. If internet is disconnected then it will just install from your Hard disk.

Comment: If you run wubi.exe standalone, it requires the internet. If you run it from an Ubuntu desktop CD, or with the desktop CD ISO in the same folder, then wubi.exe will use this without downloading a new one. But you should still be connected to the internet or it will bypass the important MD5 checksum test. Note: if the ISO is good, wubi.exe will not download a new one - so disconnecting from the internet is not a good idea.

Comment: i am pretty sure that wubi try to download latest update if it has any in server even when wubi not standalone.